# Convert a slice of strings into slice of float32

Tags: go, split, slice

In my program, I add a string of numbers (ex: 54 43.3 -43.2) to a slice via bufio scanner. Then I want to split the slice at each space into another slice to convert it to float32. Here is what i have:

```
var newSlice []float32
sliceScan = scanner.Text()
    s := strings.Split(sliceScan, " ")
    for i:= 0; i < len(s); i+=1 {
        newSlice[i] = (float32) s[i]
    }
```

when I run this I get this error:

```
syntax error: unexpected s at the end of statement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strconv.ParseFloat`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat):

```
var newSlice []float32
sliceScan = scanner.Text()
s := strings.Split(sliceScan, " ")
for i:= 0; i < len(s); i+=1 {
    f64, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s[i], 32)
    newSlice = append(newSlice, float32(f64))
}
```

or probably better:

```
sliceScan = scanner.Text()
s := strings.Split(sliceScan, " ")
newSlice := make([]float32, len(s), len(s))
for i:= 0; i < len(s); i+=1 {
    f64, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s[i], 32)
    newSlice[i] = float32(f64)
}
```

Comment: Great it seem to work, but I receive a panic index out of range exception on the line I assign newSlice to the float but values are not null

Comment: sorry, didn't notice the slice didn't have a length yet, see edit.